# Need to define dictionary without making changes to it

Tags: python, dictionary, passwords, cloud

I am trying to do a password saver, where users can insert a password and it will save to a computer. I started with

```
password = str(input("What is your password that you want to save?"))
url = str(input("Which is the site that you want your password to save to?"))
password_saved = {url : password}
with open('password_saved', 'wb') as password_saved_file:
 pickle.dump(password_saved, password_saved_file)
print(password_saved)
```

However, `password_saved = {url:password}` resets the whole dictionary in to that one, so if you run it, it will just resets to only one, insead of saving all of it. So, I tried to replace it with:

```
password_saved[url] = password
```

But, then, it will say it is not defined. How can I define the dictionary without making any changes to it, including blank-spacing it?

Comment: You need to *make changes* to the dictionary. You are actually *defining a new one here*. Thats the problem

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining how I can do that?

Comment: @idiotic_nub Do you want to store password for a single website? if not then perhaps you need to open the file in append mode.

Comment: @Hetal Thacker To your question, no, I am not storing a password for a single website. But, If I use appened, I will recive error, because I am using a dictionary, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code is all fine. But, if you put in the same value 2 times, it won't show. Make sure to try different URLs for each one to make sure that everything works.

Answer (score 1):

First, declare a dictionary then pass index and value to the dictionary.

```
password_saved = {}
password_saved[url] = password
```

Comment: Yes, but If I do that, then password_saved will reset to blank because I just declared it to be blank on the first line. Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: @idiotic_nub you need to *deserialize your pickle*, modify the resulting dictionary, then *researalize it*.

Comment: @juanpa.arriviilaga I don't really understand what you mean by reserialize and deserialize my pickle. Would you mind giving me an example?

Answer (score 0):

when you say "it" is not defined, do you mean the dictionary? If so, this could just be a problem of initializing it before you call it. Right now, you are creating a new dictionary named "password_saved" with only one entry. It should look something like

```
password_saved = {}

...

password = str(input("What is your password that you want to save?"))
url = str(input("Which is the site that you want your password to save to?"))
password_saved[url] = password
with open('password_saved', 'wb') as password_saved_file:
    pickle.dump(password_saved, password_saved_file)
print(password_saved)
```

Comment: Yes, but if I do password_saved = {} then it will resest to a blank dictonary when I run it, I only want to define the dictionary, but I don't want to make changes to it.

Comment: you have to create the dictionary at some point. Do it when you start the program. It won't save your dictionary after the program ends if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: I mean that when I do password_saved = {} and the last run I did, I did 
password_saved = {'https://youtube.com' : 'password' }
then instead of that, the dictionary will turn it back to blank.

Comment: That would work to initialize the dictionary as well, you shouldn't have any problems using password_saved[url] = password. try it again like that and let me know what happens, because there is no issue with that statement.